# passing props from parent to child (while the child is the parent himself) react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there is a **Chat** component (parent), it passes the value of props, which stores the data *`id, img Id, chatName`* in **Conversation** (child), in which they are rendered. the **Conversation** component has a **ConversationItem** component, that is, **Conversation** is the parent of the **ConversationItem**. The ImgId must be passed from the **Conversation** component to the **ConversationItem**. to draw it there.

Here is an example of my code

**Chat**

```
const Chat = () => {
return (
    <div className='app1'>
        <ConversationList/>
        {
            user.map(conversation =>

                <Conversation
                    key={conversation.id}
                    data={conversation}
                />
            )
        }

    </div>
);
}
export default Chat;
```

**Conversation**

```
export default function Conversation(props) {
        const {id, imgId, chatName} = props.data;
        const messages = JsonData;
        return (
    
            <div>
                <div >
                    <img src={imgId} />
                </div>
                <div >
                    {messages.map((message) => {
                            return (
                                <ConversationItem message={message} imgId={imgId} key={message.mes_id}/>)
                        }
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**ConversationItem**

```
const ConversationItem = ({message}, imgId) => {
    return (
        <div>
                    <div className="img_cont_msg">
                        <img src={imgId.data}/>
                    </div>
                    <div classname = "msg-text">
                        
                            {message.text_msg}
                    </div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default ConversationItem;
```

at the moment, the code transmits something and outputs not a placeholder, but a void. if  I do

```
<img src={imgId.data}/>
```

to

```
<img src={imgId}/>
```

the placeholder image not found will be displayed. how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly destructuring the props in the *ConversationItem* component. Instead do this:

```
const ConversationItem = ({ message, imgId }) => {
```

Comment: thanks, it helped. if suddenly someone is faced with the same problem, you should also change this `<img src={imgId}/>`